# Use Dict Comprehension to modify Values that contain lists

Tags: python, pandas

How might I refactor this loop into a Dict Comprehension? Should I?

```
for key,val in myDict.items():
    if '[' in val:
        myDict[key] = (ast.literal_eval(val))
```

For context, some of the values in the dictionary are lists, but formatted as strings; they come from an excel file. Anytime '[' is encountered in a cell, I want the dictionary value to be the literal cell value, not a string of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```py
{key: ast.literal_eval(val) if '[' in val else val for key, val in myDict.items()}
```

In my opinion, for this case List Comprehension is less understandable than classic loop.

Comment: Yes, that functionally works, setting myDict = {your answer}.
Looking at it now, it is not as clear as the loop. I'll mull it over some more. Thanks for the solution!